# Read JSON object in Powershell 2.0

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell 2.0 (cannot make an upgarde to V3.0 as of now) and I want to read the JSON object from bellow:

```json
{"DevResults":[{"TechnologyName":"AD","RuleName":"SOA account (user logon/display name)","OutputValue":"SOADevClientCenter"},
                {"TechnologyName":"AD","RuleName":"SOA account (pre-Windows 2000)","OutputValue":"SOADevCliCen"},
 "ProdResults":[{"TechnologyName":"AD","RuleName":"SOA account (user logon/display name)","OutputValue":"SOAClientCenter"},                 
                {"TechnologyName":"AD","RuleName":"BPM Service Account (pre-Windows 2000)","OutputValue":"BPM_CliCen_05"}]}
```

Answer (score 30):

You probably have the System.Web.Extensions available, and as such you can load that assembly and use the [JSON parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) that is available. Here is a quick sample:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$json = "{a:1,b:2,c:{nested:true}}"
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$obj = $ser.DeserializeObject($json)
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: powershell V2 runns off .net 2.0. this library is in 3.5 which unless you make sure to have .net 3.5+ installed, it wont work. granted, most will have it installed, but its an added dependency.

Comment: LOL (dueling edits). Yeah, technically PowerShell v2 runs off *CLR* 2. *If* .net 3.5 is installed, it's an expansion on top of .net 2.x -- but just be aware that you can't count on it being available if you're in PowerShell 2 ... (and let's not talk about LoadWithPartialName here...)

Comment: `$psObj = New-Object PSObject -Property $ser.DeserializeObject($json)` is also really handy.