# Parse JSON into Hashtable

Tags: json, parsing, powershell, hashtable

How do I parse the following JSON into hashtable in PowerShell? I want to pair car name ("BMW") as key and color ("Dark Gray") as value in the hashtable.

```
{
  "Car": [
    {"BMW": "Dark Gray"},
    {"Audi": "Yellow"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$json = @'
{
  "Car": [
    {"BMW": "Dark Gray"},
    {"Audi": "Yellow"}
  ]
}
'@

$ht = @{}

ConvertFrom-Json $json | Select-Object -Expand 'Car' | ForEach-Object {
    $ht[$_.PSObject.Properties.Name] = $_.PSObject.Properties.Value
}
```

If you're stuck with PowerShell v2, but have at least .Net Framework 3.5 you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17602226/1630171) instead:

```
$json = @'
...
'@

$ht = @{}

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web.Extensions')
$serializer = New-Object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$serializer.DeserializeObject($json).Values.GetEnumerator() |
    ForEach-Object { $_ } |
    ForEach-Object { $ht[($_.Keys -join '')] = ($_.Values -join '') }
```

If that also isn't possible, but your key/value pairs are always on one (separate) line, you could extract the data with a regular expression (although I wouldn't recommend that approach):

```
$json = @'
...
'@

$ht = @{}

$json -split "`n" | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '\{"(.*?)": "(.*?)"\}'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $ht[$matches[1]] = $matches[2]
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to write a JSON parser yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, my powershell version is 2.0(no CoverFrom-Json) and that's the standard for this assignment. (I know it doesn't make sense). Does powershell 2.0 support similar functionality?

Comment: @Taewan Not really. There are some different approaches, though. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell v6 it's built-in with [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6):

```
$hashtable = '{ "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2" }' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

For example:

```
PS> $hashtable["key1"]
value1
```