# Powershell - get contents from other file

Tags: powershell, ini

I'm just creating a simple powershell script to check if a service is running, and if not, to send an email. (This is already working).

What I would like to do is, to have config file, where I can set some attributes like mail recipient, service name(s), and some more.

Question: Which type should I choose for my config file (is there a better way than .txt?)?
The background of this question is, that I don't want to parse a txt file in my powershell script to get all these attribute values. Is there a way to declare these attributes in my config file to get and address them easily in powershell later? 
(Like a global variable set in the config-file and retrievable in my .ps1-file;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using xml.

create XML file looked like this,
`Setting.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings>
    <EmailSettings>
        <SMTPServer>smtp.server.net</SMTPServer>
        <SMTPPort>25</SMTPPort>
        <MailFrom>mail@from.net</MailFrom>
        <MailTo>mail@to.net</MailTo>
    </EmailSettings>
</Settings>
```

then import it in your script, `.ps1`

```
[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "your_path\Settings.xml"

$smtpsettings = @{
    To = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailTo
    From = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailFrom
    Subject = "I am a subject"
    SmtpServer = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.SMTPServer
    }
```

Comment: This looks nice.
Maybe the better solution for me as all our servers have still installed powershell v1.0 :(

Comment: @Tobi123 this is not because powershell.exe resides in a folder nammed V1.0 that it runs powershell V1.  Please use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major ` to determine the correct installed version

Comment: This says, a v2.0 is installed. Just trying the xml-solution. Looks good at first sight.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a hashtable of your configuration and store these settings in a json file. You can convert the hashtable using this snippet:

```
$config = @{
    "mail" = "test@test.com"
    "service names" = @("srv1", "srv2")
}

$config | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "c:\test.json"
```

And convert it back using:

```
$config = (gc "c:\test.json" -raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now you can access these values using `$config.mail`

Comment: note that *json cmdlet were introduced in PS V3.  You could check this question if you want something similar for V2  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077854/powershell-2-0-convertfrom-json-and-convertto-json-implementation