# PowerShell 2.0 ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json implementation exception "A circular reference was detected"

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using there functions to serialize and deserialize objects in Powershell 2.0 from question [PowerShell 2.0 ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077854/powershell-2-0-convertfrom-json-and-convertto-json-implementation)

```
function ConvertTo-Json20([object] $item){
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer
    return $ps_js.Serialize($item) 
}

function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item){ 
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions 
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer
    return $ps_js.DeserializeObject($item) 
}
```

But when i run example:

```
$json = "[{'a':'b'},{'c':'d'}]"
$o = ConvertFrom-Json20 $json
$newJson = ConvertTo-Json20 $o
```

I've got error:

```
Exception calling "Serialize" with "1" argument(s): "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of t
ype 'System.Management.Automation.PSParameterizedProperty'."
At line:4 char:28
+     return $ps_js.Serialize <<<< ($item)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

How can I resolve this error?

P.S.
I apologize in advance. What was not able to add a comment to the original question ...

Comment: FYI Your code works well in PowerShell 5.0

Comment: There was a missing " in the line where you assign json string. I have edited the question. It was a typo, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes, it was. Copy-paste error.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you! Add as answer.

Comment: Explanation of comma magic: https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problem in code:

1. PowerShell enumerate collections, so instead of one array `ConvertFrom-Json20` return two dictionaries. It is not big deal by itself, but:
2. `return` statement in PowerShell v2 wrap returned objects by `PSObject`. As result `$o` contain array with two `PSObject`, and JSON serializer can not work with them properly.

To prevent collection enumeration you can use unary comma operator. This operator create array with single element, and array will be enumerated instead of collection. And since PowerShell return output even without `return` statement, you can just remove it.

Comment: Can you explain that part with "use unary comma operator"? I cannot figure out how I can solve the similar problem.