# Get a json value using powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I know this is super easy using powershell 3.0.  Alas I am using v2 for now.

So, say I have a json file (config.json) that looks like this:

```
{
    "environment": "dev",
    "SomeKey": "SomethingElse",
    "AnotherKey":  "More Here",
    "stuff": {
        "More": "Stuff Here"
    },
    // More stuff here
}
```

**Is there a way I can get the value of "AnotherKey" using powershell (v2.0)?**

Update:
It is probably safe to say that in this case, `"AnotherKey":` will not appear in the file anywhere else.

Comment: You might want to check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077854/powershell-2-0-convertfrom-json-and-convertto-json-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested from the link I gave in the comment:

```
function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item){ 
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer

    #The comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell
    return ,$ps_js.DeserializeObject($item)
}

$json = @"
{
    "environment": "dev",
    "SomeKey": "SomethingElse",
    "AnotherKey":  "More Here",
    "stuff": {
        "More": "Stuff Here"
    }     
}
"@

$a = ConvertFrom-Json20 $json
```

Result is:

```
$a.AnotherKey
More Here
```

Notice I had to edit you json example (extra comma + removed the commented out code)