# Json circular reference in powershell 2.0 with javascriptSerializer

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0, javascriptserializer

I´m writing a script in powershell 2.0 and an upgrade to 3.0 or higher is not possible right now. In this script I try to serialize some data to JSON with the code from this link ([PowerShell 2.0 ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077854/powershell-2-0-convertfrom-json-and-convertto-json-implementation)):

```
function ConvertTo-Json20([object] $item){
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer
    return $ps_js.Serialize($item)
}
```

My problem is that I somehow get a circular reference and I really don´t know why. I set up a litte piece of test data and the structure looks in powershell like this:

```
$testRoot = @{
    "id" = "1"
    "children" = @( 
        @{
            "id" = "2"
            "children" = @( 
                @{
                    "id" = "2";
                };
                @{
                    "id" = "3";
                }
            );
        };
        @{
            "id" = "4"
            "children" = @( 
                @{
                    "id" = "5";
                }
            );
        }
    )
}
```

I know it looks junky, but I just need it in this format.

The structures I need to serialize have a few more layers, so even more "children" and there is the point where it gets strange.

When I try this:

```
ConvertTo-Json20 $testRoot
```

everything works fine. The structure gets parsed like this:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "children":[
        {
            "id":"2",
            "children":[
               {
                   "id":"2"
               },
               {
                   "id":"3"
               }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"4",
            "children":[
               {
                   "id":"5"
               }
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

But now comes the problem. As mentioned the structure has more layers, so I try this which just sets the data in an array.

```
ConvertTo-Json20 @($testRoot)
```

But it does not work I just get an error message saying:

```
Exception in method "Serialize" with 1 argument(s):  
"While serializing an object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSParameterizedProperty" a circular reference was discovered."
At C:\Users\a38732\Desktop\Temp.ps1:34 symbol:28
+     return $ps_js.Serialize <<<< ($item)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

(I translated the error message from german, so there might be some words different in the english version...)

Comment: I just tried it with Powershell 4.0 on another machine and it worked with the build in json serializer.
    ConvertTo-Json @($testRoot)

Comment: Does somebody know how to tweek the javascriptSerializer to serialize that? The documentation does not help very much...

Comment: Your example is malformed.  Entries in arrays are separated by commas, not semicolons.  The function also doesn't take an array, it takes a single `[object]`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - agree that array elements are **normally** separated by commas, but actually the `@( )` [array subexpression operator is special](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#special-operators). To quote: "_Returns the result of one or more statements as an array_."  e.g. `@(Get-Date; Start-Sleep -s 1; Get-Date)`.  And since an `array` is a `object`, the function is perfectly valid. One problem is that `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` is useless for anything but **simple** JSON.

Comment: If it is just about *serializing* a (complex) object for reuse by the same system or exchanging with another *PowerShell* system, you might consider the [`ConvertTo-Expression` cmdlet from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=convertto-expression&x=0&y=0) which is downwards compatible with PSv2.0. The results can easily be invoked (deserialized) with `Invoke-Expression` or just an ampersand (`&`) or *dot sourcing* a `.ps1` file containing the results.

Answer (score 4):

One problem is the use of the `JavaScriptSerializer` class itself. As of this date the [documentation itself concedes it should not be used to serialize nor deserialize JSON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). To quote:

> [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) should be used serialization and deserialization.

If you're able to use third-party libraries like [Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json), here's a simple function that does what you need given the data structure in the OP:

```
function ConvertTo-JsonNet {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] $object,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string]$jsonNetPath,
        [switch]$indent,
        [switch]$preserveReferencesHandling
    )
    Add-Type -Path $jsonNetPath;

    $formatting = if ($indent.IsPresent) { [Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting]::Indented; }
    else { [Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting]::None; }

    $settings = New-Object Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings;
    if ($preserveReferencesHandling.IsPresent) { 
        $settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = [Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling]::Objects;
    }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject($object, $formatting, $settings);
}
```

Simple usage, assuming `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is in the same directory as your script:

```
$dllPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll';
ConvertTo-JsonNet @($testRoot) $dllPath;
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"1","children":[{"id":"2","children":[{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]},{"id":"4","children":[{"id":"5"}]}]}]
```

You can manually download the .dll from the [nuget package project site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). It has a `.nupkg` file extension, but it's a zipped archive, so rename the extension to `.zip` and you're set. In the `lib` sub-directory there are .dll files for .NET versions from 2.0 through 4.5.